# Firemonkey - How to position a new form under a TComponent

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am developing an application for Windows/Apple with Delphi 10 and Firemonkey.
My main form has a TButton.
When I press the TButton I would like to create and positioning Form1 exactly under the TButton.
Here there is my code:

```
//Transposes the coordinates in the context of the form. 
myTPointF := TButton.LocalToAbsolute(TButton.Position.Point);

//Transposes the coordinates in the context of the screen. 
myTPointF := ClientToScreen(myTPointF);

Form1.Top := FloatToStr(myTPointF.X) + Round(TButton.Height);
Form1.Left := FloatToStr(myTPointF.Y);
```

And if the TButton is near the Point(0,0) of the form (not the screen) it works, but the more is away from this point the more Form1 is wrong when i open it.

Link for the image:
https://ibb.co/85dfr9R
https://ibb.co/t2stMHv

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Did you mean *all* Apple products? Or just one particular OS such as MacOS? Surely you don't want such a thing in iOS, right?

Comment: @DavidS Welcome to Stackowerflow. The members of this community store images within their posts by the SO engine. Avoid using external links as they will probably become unreachable and the Q will become useless.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `LocalToAbsolute()` only `ClientToScreen(Button1.Position.Point)`. You also have the `X` and `Y` swapped in the code you present.

You also better set the second form visible first, because other forms than the main form are not necessarily created before they are shown for the first time in the `Fmx` framework.

This works:

```
procedure TForm14.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  newpos: TPointF;
begin
  Form15.Visible := True;

  newpos := ClientToScreen(Button1.Position.Point);
  Form15.Left := Round(newpos.X);
  Form15.Top  := Round(newpos.Y+Button1.Height);
end;
```